# How does exactly "new" folder work in maildir?

Tags: maildir

I am using isync/mbsync to sync my IMAP accounts with local machine. From the specification of Maildir format, I understood that basically subfolder `new` equals to unread messages?

Is it really so? I'm using `aerc` email client and basically once that client displays incoming message in its viewer, the emails are immediately moved into `cur` subfolder. I'm seeing the messages as unread in the message list and I have not yet opened them. I'd assume that the messages stay in `new` until I open them.

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic states of messages: new, unread and read.

New messages are messages that **arrived since you last opened your inbox folder**. In some mail clients (generally most IMAP-based ones), once you open the inbox folder, the new messages immediately become unread. That's probably your case.

In some other mail clients, for example `mutt` which I'm using, messages are changed from new to unread when you exit the inbox folder (ie. either quit the program or change to a different folder) applying changes (because in `mutt` all changes to mailbox are applied on exit). However, you can choose to exit program discarding all changes, in which case new messages still remain new.

The `new` subfolder contains only new messages (in the above sense). The `curr` folder contains both unread and read messages, a flag on each message decides that.